# No Base and Custom forms in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, propel, symfony-forms

We had this concept of baseform and custom form in symfony 1.4. In symfony2, I believe this concept is dropped. I am using propel:form:generate to generate forms, am I supposed to make modifications to the generated form Type itself? What if I have schema changes and all my modifications get lost?

Is there standard way of doing this? I have just started using symfony2 from symfony1.4.

Answer (score 0):

This depends very much on what you want to do. One way to do this is to create a custom form type and use that type as parent type of all your forms. The second is to write a form type extension and apply it to type "form", which is the base type of all core and usually also of all custom types.